# Laço de repetição em algoritmo de lógica de programação

Tags: algoritmo, portugol

Estou com duvidas nesta questão:

Escreva um algoritmo que solicite a idade de várias pessoas (UTILIZE O REPITA). Informe o total de pessoas com menos de 25 anos e o total de pessoas com mais de 50 anos. O programa termina quando idade for negativa (Não deve ser utilizada na contagem).

cheguei até aqui mas empaquei pois não sei utilizar muito bem o repita.

```
Algoritmo "semnome"

var
    idade, cont, f1, f2: inteiro
    outro: caracter
    inicio
    cont <- 0
    f1 <- 0
    f2 <- 0

repita
    escreva("Informe a idade: ")
    leia(idade)
    cont <- cont + 1

    se (idade <= 25) entao
        f1 <- f1 + 1
    senao
        se ((idade >= 26) e (idade <= 51)) entao
            f2 <- f2 + 1
        fimse
    fimse

    escreval("Outra pessoa [S/N]: ")
    leia(outro)
ate (outro = "N")

escreval("Total de pessoas informadas: ", cont)
escreval("Faixa 1: ", f1)
escreval("Faixa 2: ", f2)
```

poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Isso é Portugol?

Comment: Favor, insira a linguagem de programação.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o comando `interrompa` para para o repita após a leitura dos dados:

Segue o código:

```
se (idade < 0) entao
   interrompa
fimse
```

Segue ilustração:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

veja seu código rodando perfeitamente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código inteiro usado:

```
var
idade, cont, f1, f2: inteiro
outro: caracter

inicio
// Seção de Comandos 
cont <- 0
f1 <- 0
f2 <- 0

repita

escreva("Informe a idade: ")
leia(idade)

se (idade < 0) entao
   interrompa
fimse

cont <- cont + 1

se (idade < 25) entao
   f1 <- f1 + 1
senao se (idade > 50) entao
      f2 <- f2 + 1
fimse

escreval("Outra pessoa [S/N]: ")
leia(outro)

ate (outro = "N")

escreval("Total de pessoas informadas: ", cont)
escreval("Faixa 1: ", f1)
escreval("Faixa 2: ", f2)

fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Verdade mesmo o lance do negativo. Interpretei errado a pergunta. Valeu!

Comment: Só está errado na sua resposta as comparações de `<= 25`e o `senao se ((idade >= 26) e (idade <= 51)) entao`

Comment: Normal! após copiar o código dele retirei só um `fimse`(pois tinha 2 sem necessidade), rodei e funcionou, daí fui direto pro interrompa e tbm não me atentei ao `<=` dele.

Comment: "_Informe o total de pessoas com menos de 25 anos_": `idade < 25`... "_e o total de pessoas com mais de 50 anos_": `idade > 50`

Comment: Algumas pessoas tem dificuldades em traduzir texto para código, e isso não deveria acontecer com programadores porque eles trabalham justamente com coisas exatas. Quando diz "_menor que 25_", o `25` não está incluido, vai só até o `24`.

Comment: você tem razão... correção feita!

Comment: Faltou só corrigir o `< 26`